# interact with one object individually inside while loop

Tags: php, sql, while-loop, phpmailer

I have a contact form inside a while loop, which will send an email to the user displayed in the while loop. But with this structure I would send an email to all objects inside the loop. I don't know how to escape the while loop in this case.

```
... while($row = $sql->fetchObject()){
     ... echo $row->userMail;
         echo '<form ...><input name="contactMail"><...submit></form>';
         if(isset($_POST['visitorMail']{
            mail($toUserMail,$subject,$body_containsVisitorMail,$headers);
              //this will send an email to all "objects" displayed in within the while loop -> problem

   }
}
```

Comment: Do not put the destination address in the form. It will be exploited as a spam gateway. Also it looks like you’re mixing up the form itself with the code to process its content, doesn’t make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you need to check value of `$_POST['contactMail']` with the current iterated one:

```
while($row = $sql->fetchObject()){
    echo $row->mail;
    echo '<form ...><input name="contactMail" value="' . $row->mail . '"><...submit>
    <input type="hidden" name="itemId" value="' . $row->id . '"></form>';
    if(isset($_POST['contactMail']) && $_POST['itemId'] == $row->id) {
        mail($toRowMail,$subject,$body,$headers);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but the input field is actually for the visitor to put in their email address. So the 'contactMail' and the '$row->mail' are two different addresses. The contactMail is just for the $body.

Comment: Then why do you send email in a while loop? Check `if ($_POST[''])` after `while` loop.

Comment: well how should I know to which object to send the email. Let's say I have a few objects displayed with the while loop. For each object there is an extra form to send an email to. I would need a way to check on which form the user submits it.

Comment: Add a hidden field to each form with `id` or some other unique field. Check if value of this passed field equals to current one. Updated my script, check it.